# How do you pass a function as a parameter in the replace function in Kotlin?

Tags: regex, kotlin, replace

I'm trying to replace any repeated character with the character and the number of repetitions. For example, "aaabccccddefff" would become "a3bc4d2ef3".

I know how to do this in JavaScript.

```
function repeatedLetters(s) {
    return s.replace(/(.)(\1+)/g, (wholePattern, capture1, capture2) => `${capture1}${capture2.length + 1}`)
}
```

Does anyone know the syntax for Kotlin?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I figured it out.

```
fun repeatedLetters(s: String): String {
    return s.replace(Regex("(.)(\\1+)"), {"${it.groupValues[1]}${it.groupValues[2].length + 1}"})
}
```